# Creating Jar and Tar using Gradle 5.x

Tags: java, gradle, build

I'm writing up a new Gradle script for a legacy project being migrated over to it.

I originally wrote the script using Gradle 4.x DSL but I have decided to upgrade it over to 5.x for better future proofing.

One of my tasks was charged with creating the jar by setting the jar name and extension and creating a new file under a folder of my projects root directory.

When I migrated the script over to gradle 5.X the following properties have become deprecated:

baseName, extension, archiveName and destinationDir.

I have tried adjusting those to the new convention but I'm having issues with those properties being unable to be found:

```
Could not set unknown property 'archiveDestinationDirectory' for task ':jar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar."
```

I have tried finding a solution online to this but I have yet to find either a proper way to do it or an example that uses Gradle 5.x

Now the second question revolves around the notion of creating a tar. Again I have found no good example to show this. So far my script does this, which will create a tar but without preserving the correct file hierarchy:

```
task createTar(type: Tar) {
    archiveBaseName = 'info_tar'
    archiveExtension = 'gz'
    compression = Compression.GZIP
    from ('..') {
        include('bin/**')
        include('sounds/**')
        include('classes/**')
    }
    archiveFileName = archiveBaseName.get() + '.' + archiveExtension.get()
    //cleanup of temporary directories
    delete BIN_TARGET, SOUNDS_TARGET, CLASSES_TARGET
}
```

My goal is to produce a tar that contains the folders bin, sounds, classes. Can anyone lend a hand in achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

- baseName: [The documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar:baseName) shows that it's deprecated in favor of `archiveBaseName`
- extension: [The documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar:extension) shows that it's deprecated in favor of `archiveExtension`
- archiveName: [The documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar:archiveName) shows that it's deprecated in favor of `archiveFileName`
- [destinationDir](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar:destinationDir): The documentation shows that it's deprecated in favor of `destinationDirectory`

There is no `archiveDestinationDirectory` property in Jar. [The documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:destinationDirectory) shows that the correct property is named `destinationDirectory`.

To include the directories themselves into the tar, you need to use, instead of what you're using:

```
from('..') {
  include('bin/**')
  include('sounds/**')
  include('classes/**')
}
```

Comment: Yes I have gone through the documentation and even though I tried using the suggested replacements I'm still getting errors.

For example when I try to create a jar with a custom naming naming convention like so:

`archiveFileName = archiveBaseName + '.' + archiveExtension`

I still get the following error `No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultPropertyState.plus() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [.]
Possible solutions: value(java.lang.Object), is(java.lang.Object), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), split(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), get()`

Comment: That's because the properties aren't of type String. They are of type Property<String> ? Use archiveBaseName.get() + '.' + archiveExtension.get()

Comment: OK thank you very much for that. I got the jar to work fine, but still my createTar task does nothing (updated the original question).

Comment: Use --info to find out why it does nothing. My guess is that the directories are not in '..', and that there is this nothing to put into the tar file.

Comment: Indeed this was it. I corrected those and it worked fine. The only thing left to figure is to how to create the tarball under the project's root dir. If set nothing as a destinationDirectory then nothing is created. If I specify a directory everything works fine. Ideally I would like to spew it out under the root dir.

Comment: $projectDir is... the project dir.

Comment: Thank you very much I got everything sorted out

Comment: I want to set the `destinationDirectory` property but I can't because it's a `DirectoryProperty` and don't know how to create it.
I can do `archiveFileName = "some_string"` but not `destinationDirectory = "some dir"`. Any ideas?